# how to get the data in a diagonal manner and sum it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below.

[image]

I want to get a sum of the diagonal values like this from the dataframe.

1-12

2-26+3 =29

3-5+5+5=15

4-34+6+14+2

like this it will continue.

Can anyone able to provide me the python code to solve it.

Comment: Kindly share dataframe as text not pics. Also add the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with something like this:

```
import numpy as np

dict(zip(df.index.values, [sum(np.diagonal(df.values[::-1], offset=i)) for i in range(-len(df)+1, 1)]))
```

What it does is:

- gets the ascending diagonal given an offset `np.diagonal(df.values[::-1], offset=i)`
- sums it `sum(...)`
- for each row present in the df `sum(...) for i in range(-len(df)+1, 1)`
- zips these sums with the index values `zip(df.index.values, ...)`
- and generates a dictionary, or whatever you want to store it `dict(...)`

Comment: Fantastic .. it worked for me. Thanks for explaining the code so nicely.